# How can I change the output of tf.cond to tuple in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

When I feed tuple of tensors into tf.cond, the output becomes a list not a tuple.

```
output = tf.cond(sw_c, lambda: (a,b), lambda: (c,d))
```

How can  I change it to the list to the tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it in a tuple

```
output = tuple(tf.cond(sw_c, lambda: (a,b), lambda: (c,d)))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! By the way, why it should be tuple() not just ()?

Comment: It's a good practice: always made explicit what are you doing.

Comment: Actually, the first one(your suggestion) is working while the second one is not. I don't know the reason...